# How can I make what I want array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm a student who has just studied javaScript.

I'm trying to solve an algorithm problem, but I can't solve the problem.

just simple Q ... but I couldn't solve the problem.

[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]

please advice me How should make it what I want array

I need to turn a 2D array into a 1D array.

result i want [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ]

I've tried to do many thing.

At first I thought it would be easy , but I couldn't.
I tried many methods, but I didn't get the result.

```
let a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
    a.toString().split('').join('')
let result = [];
result.push(a) // [ '1,2', '1,3', '2,1', '2,3' ] // string
```

How can I get the results [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ]?

Comment: [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] this is an invalid sintax

Comment: Nit: You probably want `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2]` as your output. The result you're expecting doesn't look like a 1D array. Your 2nd line doesn't do anything because the result isn't stored. Tip: if you have an `element` in `a`, you can use `element[0]` and `element[1]` to extract the 1st and 2nd number respectively (which can be pushed into your `result` array)

Comment: `.split('').join('')` is completely redundant as it essentially does nothing. leaving you with `a.toString()`. Even then though the result of this is ignored as it's not assigned to anything.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)? which would turn `[[1,2], [1,3]` into `[1, 2, 1, 3]`

Comment: Are you trying to turn the array into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest result I get :

```
let a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
let res = '';

a.forEach(b => {
    res += `[${b}],`
});

console.log(res); // [1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],
```

I hope I helped !

**Update**

To answer OP from the comments below :

```
let a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3,2 ] ]
let res = a.map(cell => cell = +cell.join(''))
console.log(res); // [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]
```

`.map()` : [see the MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

On the first call `cell` will be `[ 1, 2 ]`. Using `.join('')` on it will result in `"12"`. Having a `+` sign before the `.join('')` call will parse the result in number.

I hope I explained the process well :)

Comment: wow.... thank you !!!! genius
I studying to use higher-order functions
what if make result [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32] 
is it possible??

Comment: Yes, based on the same logic you can replace the corresponding line with `res += \`[${b.join('')}],\``

Comment: if I don't want result that separate array result, just 1d array like

let a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
result = [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]

that logic result -> [12][13][21][23][31][32]
but want to make result = [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]
is it possible?? .. i shouldn't...I guess I'm stupid.

Comment: What is the result you want ?

Comment: [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32] I want this result. but I couldn't make it. 
just want me to know it couldn't make it or  it could make it.
if you know, tell me how to make it

Comment: OMG WHAT the Hell!!!
that's mean "Having a + sign before the .join('') call will parse the result in number" I didn't know!!!
I feel good because I feel like I've learned something great.

I've been studying JavaScript for about 5 months.
There are many difficulties in preparing for algorithm tests. 
May I ask for some advice?
Wouldn't it be best to just solve a lot of algorithms?
any way, you are so great !! thank you so much Alex

Comment: I've been using JS for 5 years now, and I am still learning new things sometimes haha ! My best advice to learn more about JS is to watch/read content (youtube, articles, teaching blended or forums) and practicing (a lot). You can look for exercices on the Internet, or start little projects on your own. It's like learning a new language (English, French, ...). If you have the opportunity to learn in an enterprise, it's even better as you will also learn best practices. HF with JS ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what you mean here, but i believe what you want is this

```
let a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ];
let arr = [];
for (i=0;i<a.length;++i){
   var toTXT = a[i][0]+","+a[i][1];

    arr[i] = toTXT;  
}
console.log(arr) // (6) ['1,2', '1,3', '2,1', '2,3', '3,1', '3,2']
```

Comment: It's not the result I want. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ];
let newArr = [];

for(let a of arr){
  for(let b of a){
    newArr.push(b);
  }
}

console.log( newArr ); // this is 1 dimensional array.

/*
your request :
[ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ]
that was an invalid sintax. you cant. 
the valid one is :
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ];
*/
```